# A problem on random series

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X_1, X_2,\dots, $ be an independent sequence of random variables and $E[X_n] = 0 \forall n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \operatorname{Var}(X_n) < \infty$. I need to prove that $\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n \right) < \infty$. How to proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ converges in mean square. Observe that
$$
\operatorname E\biggl|\sum_{n=1}^NX_n-\sum_{n=1}^MX_n\biggr|^2=\sum_{n=M+1}^N\operatorname EX_n^2<\varepsilon
$$
for large values of $N$ and $M$ since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname EX_n^2<\infty$.

If the series of random variables converges in mean square, then the sequence of variances converges and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Var}\biggl[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\biggr]=\operatorname{Var}\biggl[\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k\biggr]
$$
(see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702559/convergence-in-mean-square-implies-convergence-of-variance) for a proof).

Answer (score 1):

If you call $Y_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ and $Y:=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} X_k$, $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ pointwise. Furthermore, by hypothesis  $ \exists   M>0$ s.t.  $\forall n$  $E[Y_n^2]<M$.

Now we use Fatou's Lemma and we obtain $E[Y^2]=E[\liminf Y_n^2]\leq \liminf E[Y_n^2]\leq M$