# convergence almost surely implies convergence of variance?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, variance, expected-value

Does $X_{n} \to X$ almost surely imply that $Var[X_{n}] \to Var[X]?$

I saw this post

[convergence in mean square implies convergence of variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702559/convergence-in-mean-square-implies-convergence-of-variance)

which states that $X_{n} \to X$ in $L^{2}$ implies that $Var[X_{n}] \to Var[X]$ but does that still hold if the convergence is almost surely instead of $L^{2}$?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, because the random variables need not even to be integrable, see e.g. Example 3 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1170661/36150)

Answer (score 1):

Take $U \sim$ Uniform$[0,1]$. Let $$X_n := \sqrt{n} 1_{ \{U \leq \frac{1}{n} \} } - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ Then $X_n \to 0$ a.s. But 
$$\mathbb V [ X_n] = 1 - \frac 1 n \to 1 \neq 0$$