# Mean square convergence of the squares

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, lp-spaces

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables converging in mean square to $X$, that is,
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\Big(\big|X_n-X\big|^2\Big)=0
\end{equation}
or, in short-hand notation, $X_n\overset{\mathcal{L}^2}{\longrightarrow}X$

**Wish**: does $(1)$ imply $X_n^2\overset{\mathcal{L}^2}{\longrightarrow}X^2$?

In the accepted answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702559/convergence-in-mean-square-implies-convergence-of-variance) post it is written that $(1)$ implies $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)\to\mathbb{E}(X^2)$, but I don't know if it's enough to guarantee the convergence of the squares.

Comment: Why is $X^{2}$ in $\mathcal L^{2}$?

Comment: There’s no reason for it to be. I’m just pretending..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this would require $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_n^2-X^2|^2] = 0$, but there is no guarantee that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n^2-X^2|^2]$ is even finite.

Comment: Oh, ok... but is it true at least that $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)\to\mathbb{E}(X^2)
$?

Comment: @ric.san Yes, that is true, as the post you linked to showed